# Flex vs Eclipse RCP for ETL tools

Tags: etl, rcp

Lot of ETL tools in the market are using Eclipse RCP for providing richer development interface. However, with Flex getting open source and HTML5 coming up to speed, will we be seeing ETL tools which are based on these platforms? Also, will Flex/HTML5 development increase the complexity of tool development?
Such a tool will reduce the maintenance cost and will also provide a better interface for business teams for complex ETL development. I am not sure if such ETL tools are already available.

Thanks